# How to use multiple variables and a table that are return from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

How to use multiple variables and a table that are returned from a stored procedure?
From what I have read these variables and table should be, being returned from the stored procedure. I am at a loss as to how to access them from my C# code.

This is the relevant portion of my stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @ReaderName  nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @TrainID int;

SELECT @ReaderName = Name, @TrainID = Train_Id FROM Readers WHERE Id=@ReaderID
DECLARE @TrainName nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @LineID int;
SELECT @TrainName = Name, @LineID = Line_Id FROM Trains WHERE ID = @TrainID
DECLARE @LineName nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @LineName = Name FROM Trains WHERE ID = @LineID

DECLARE @EmailList dbo.EmailList;

INSERT INTO @EmailList SELECT Emails.EmailAddress FROM ReaderEmails JOIN Emails ON Emails.Id = ReaderEmails.Email_Id WHERE ReaderEmails.Reader_Id = @ReaderID

SELECT * FROM @EmailList;
SELECT * FROM @StatusList;
```

So I need ReaderName, TrainName, LineName, EmailList(table), and @StatusList(table).

databaseAPI is my DbContext

Here is my C# code.

```
//** get a data table with tags and antennas in it
DataTable dtTags = getDataTableTags(info.TagList.ToList());

//**call stored procedure

SqlParameter sqlParamTags = new SqlParameter("tagList", SqlDbType.Structured);
sqlParamTags.Value = dtTags;
sqlParamTags.TypeName = "TagListType";

SqlParameter sqlParamMac = new SqlParameter("@Mac", reader.MAC);
sqlParamMac.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;

string strTempMac = reader.MAC;
string command = "EXEC " + "SaveMsgData" + " @Mac, @tagList;";

var result = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)databaseAPI).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(command, sqlParamMac, sqlParamTags);
```

I have tried using ExecuteStoreQuery like so

```
var result = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)databaseAPI).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery(command, sqlParamMac, sqlParamTags);
```

but I get the following error

> The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery(string, string, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ExecutionOptions, params object[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: You probably need to look at output parameters but it isn't very clear.

Comment: I was trying to be as clear as possible. What else do you need to know? Let me know and I will update my question.

The problem with output parameters is that they don't work for TVPs I need to pass back two tables (was one now two will update momentarily)